# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when loading a class in a second project

Tags: eclipse, configuration, project

I have an Eclipse RCP plugin project that works when all the code is in one project.  There are 3 packages and I want to use one of these packages in another RCP plugin.  Therefore, I decided to move this package into a second project that can be part of both RCP workspaces. I include the second project in "Java build Path" -> "Projects" and there is a "-" in the "Order and Export" of the second project (it will not allow me to change this)

When debugging the plugin it gives "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" on a class in the second project. I cannot figure out how to connect the two projects together.  Can another please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve the problem of connecting the two projects.

In addition to Andy's two points: (1) add a dependency to the first project in the second project's manifest.mf -> Dependencies -- under both "Required plugins" and "Imported packages" add reference to the the first project (2) check the project in the "add required plug" section of the launcher... You have to export the necessary packages from the first project. This is done in the manifest.mf -> Runtime -> Exported packages

Answer (score 0):

In the depending plug-in, open META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, via *Open With...>Plug-in Manifest Editor*. On the *Dependencies* tab, ensure that your new plug-in is listed among the dependencies.

After that, in your launchers and *.products, look for a button labeled *Add Required Plug-ins*. Press it. Verify that your new plug-in has been added.

Comment: The new plug-in is now listed in the "Dependencies"->"Required plug-ins" (but not in the imported package - as it only works if the optional flag is set), and when I press the "Add Required Plug-ins" button in the "launcher->"plug-ins" the package is listed but not checked.  The same NoClassDefFoundError is given, (whether I check the new package in the launcher of not).